# Bad type with formData in nextjs 13

Tags: javascript, next.js

In my NextJS application, I retrieve the values ​​of the fields of a form with the dataForm method:

```
export async function getDataForm(formData) {
    const bodyQuery = {
        .......
        skip: formData.get("gridSkip")
    }
```

The "skip" field is a checkbox input type.
But when I display the value in a console.log, the result is a "string" type with the value "on/off".

Is it possible to have a Boolean directly?
Thanks

get a boolean return

Answer (score 0):

does doing something like this work for you?

```html
 const bodyQuery = {
        .......
        skip: formData.get("gridSkip")==="on"?true:false
    }
```

But i think you should look, how you can return directly a boolean from the checkbox, it seems strange that doesn't return it out of the box.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution works.

Indeed, I find it strange not to receive a boolean.

Comment: @daruommourad That's because In the context of form submission, only the name-value pairs of the checked `input type="checkbox"`es are submitted, the values are never converted to booleans.